# Checkbox only being checked on the first try, javascript/jquery bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I need to be able to click any element inside `.modal-interest`, and it for it to check the child-element checkbox when they are clicked.

Currently, it seems to work for the first click - but for every subsequent click, even though the code is supposed to be checking the checkbox, it does nothing.

```
$('.modal-interest strong').click(function (e) {

 input = $(this).closest('.modal-interest').find('input');

 if (input.prop('checked')) {
     input.attr('checked', false).change();
 } else {
     input.attr('checked', true).change();
 }
});
```

An accurate representation of my problem can be seen on the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/c3p5m/

Stuck with this and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.prop()` instead:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3p5m/2/)

```
 $('.modal-interest strong').click(function (e) {

     input = $(this).closest('.modal-interest').find('input');

     if (input.prop('checked')) {
         input.prop('checked', false).change();
         $('h1').html('untick it');
     } else {
         input.prop('checked', true).change();
         $('h1').html('tick it');
     }
 });
```

Now indeed, your code should look like this instead:

```
$('.modal-interest strong').click(function (e) {
    var input = $(this).closest('.modal-interest').find('input')[0];
    input.checked = !input.checked;
    $(input).change();
});
$('.modal-interest input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    $('h1').html(this.checked ? 'tick it' : 'untick it');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c3p5m/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set `checked/Unchecked`

```
input.prop('checked', false).change();
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3p5m/4/)

Answer (score 0):

The prop method should be used.

`input.prop('checked', false).change();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 $('.modal-interest').click(function () {

     var input = $(this).find('input');

     if (input.prop('checked')) {
         input.prop('checked', false).change();
         $('h1').html('untick it');
     } else {
         input.prop('checked', true).change();
         $('h1').html('tick it');
     }
});
```